# GNU ld: -z origin? -rpath $ORIGIN/../lib?

Tags: gnu, ld, elf, binutils

A legacy makefile that I'm trying to understand has `-Wl,-z,origin,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/../lib'`

OK, I see `-Wl` means the following are linker options; the commas will be replaced with spaces.

The manpage for the GNU `ld` mysteriously only says:

```
   -z keyword
       The recognized keywords are:
           :
           :
       origin
           Marks the object may contain $ORIGIN.
```

Likewise the next option `-rpath` (relative path?) contains this `$ORIGIN` suggesting it's some kind of key word but `$ORIGIN` is not otherwise mentioned in the `ld` man page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$ORIGIN` is mentioned under [Substitution Sequences](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch5.dynamic.html#substitution) in the ELF specification.  `DF_ORIGIN` is [documented as well](http://www.sco.com/developers/gabi/latest/ch5.dynamic.html#df_flags).

However, while GNU ld supports setting the `DF_ORIGIN` flag with the `-z origin` option, the dynamic loader in glibc always honors `$ORIGIN`, even if the flag is not set. This means that there is no reason to use the link editor flag when building for GNU/Linux.